# Allow HTML in TYPO3 Subheader

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I couldn't find anything about this on the web or in the documentation, so I wonder if it's possible.

```
lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.htmlSpecialChars = 0
```

Works fine for standard header and I already tried

```
lib.stdheader.20.setCurrent.htmlSpecialChars = 0
```

for subheader, but doesn't work.

Any hint is very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at **TypoScript Object Browser** in **Template** module.

You'll see, that *lib.stdheader.20* doesn't have *setCurrent* property. Instead it has bunch of properties, like *1.*, *2.*, ... and *default*. All of them correspond to header type: *h1, h2, h3 etc.* and default (which is h2).

So, you need to override *htmlSpecialChars* for each of them. Or, at least, for default, if you're not planning to use different subheader types:

```
lib.stdheader.20.1.htmlSpecialChars = 0
lib.stdheader.20.2.htmlSpecialChars = 0
...
lib.stdheader.20.default.htmlSpecialChars = 0
```

Comment: Awsome - thannks m8 : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :-

For headers :

```
lib.stdheader.10.setCurrent.htmlSpecialChars >
```

For subHeaders :

```
lib.stdheader.20.setCurrent.htmlSpecialChars >
```